# Why App is not able to receive GCM Notification in Android O?

Tags: android, service, google-cloud-messaging, intentservice

I am using the GCM inside my Application. But in Android O App stops receiving notification if it goes into background. I am using StartService for Lower API 26 and StartForgroundService for upper API 26 Android devices. Also tried JobSchedular and JobIntentService but still App is getting crashed with the below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1000010 pkg=com.teacout.devzspoon cmp=com.teacout.devzspoon/com.devzspoon.services.MyGcmListenerService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{cf40c05 u0a582 RCVR bg:+2m52s193ms idle change:uncached procs:1 proclist:22992, seq(0,0,0)}
                                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1600)
                                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1546)
                                                                           at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:669)
                                                                           at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:669)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService(WakefulBroadcastReceiver.java:99)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver.zzf(Unknown Source:23)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver.zze(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver.onReceive(Unknown Source:106)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3406)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1807) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408) 
06-05 17:30:40.508 22992-22992/com.teacout.devzspoon E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1000010 pkg=com.teacout.devzspoon cmp=com.teacout.devzspoon/com.devzspoon.services.MyGcmListenerService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{cf40c05 u0a582 RCVR bg:+2m52s193ms idle change:uncached procs:1 proclist:22992, seq(0,0,0)}
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3413)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1807)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: Main error id below:- 
 Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE

 :---Please help me if anyone have any proper solution on it

Comment: You first should use FCM instead of GCM which is deprecated now. How do you initialize your instance ?

Comment: GSM is dead. Do not try to fix it. Migrate to FCM.